# Windows: Attach to process and read debug output

Tags: debugging, winapi, process

How can I attach to another process using WinAPI? I want to read its OutputDebugStrings and be able to pause its execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a debugger with the WaitForDebugEvent() api function.  DEBUG_EVENT.DebugString supplies the text generated with OutputDebugString().  This [SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679288%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a good starting point for getting this going.